# Кнопка tkinter лезет в новое окно

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
root=Tk()
root.title("Аксенов М.А. Тест по английскому языку")
root.geometry("800x600")
root.resizable(width=2000, height=1500)

def hi():
    h=Label(root, text="Тест по английскому языку",font='Times 30', fg='#0F9')
    inpansh=Button(root,text='Продолжить',font='Times 17', command=lambda:que_1())
    h.grid(row=0)
    inpansh.grid(row=2)



def que_1():
    question=Label(root, text="Вставьте нужное слово: “ ... money on the wardrobe.”", font='Times 30', fg='#0F9')
    question22=Label(root, text="1) There is", font='Times 30', fg='#0F9')
    question333=Label(root, text="2) It is", font='Times 30', fg='#0F9')
    question4444=Label(root, text="3) There are", font='Times 30', fg='#0F9')
    answer=Entry()
    inpans=Button(root,text='  Ответить   ', font='Times 17', command=lambda:game1(que_2))
    question.grid(row=0)
    question22.grid(row=1)
    question333.grid(row=2)
    question4444.grid(row=3)
    answer.grid(row=4)
    inpans.grid(row=5)

    def game1(que_2):
        if answer.get()=='1':
            summa()
            messagebox.showinfo('Верно')
            que_2()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Неверно')
            que_2()
```

Comment: Добавьте код, на котором можно увидеть вашу проблему. Вместе с вызовами функций и импортами.

Comment: В целом, если кнопка создается не в том окне обычно из-за того, что первым параметром не то окно указано, или вообще не указано.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте так попробуем

```
def check_answer(answer, correct_answer, next_question_func):
    if answer == correct_answer:
        summa()
        messagebox.showinfo('Верно')
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Неверно')
    next_question_func()

def que_1():
    question=Label(root, text="Вставьте нужное слово: “ ... money on the wardrobe.”", font='Times 30', fg='#0F9')
    question22=Label(root, text="1) There is", font='Times 30', fg='#0F9')
    question333=Label(root, text="2) It is", font='Times 30', fg='#0F9')
    question4444=Label(root, text="3) There are", font='Times 30', fg='#0F9')
    answer=Entry()
    inpans=Button(root,text='  Ответить   ', font='Times 17', command=lambda: check_answer(answer.get(), '1', que_2))
    question.grid(row=0)
    question22.grid(row=1)
    question333.grid(row=2)
    question4444.grid(row=3)
    answer.grid(row=4)
    inpans.grid(row=5)

def que_2():
    # Код для второго вопроса
    pass
попрaвил def hi
```

def hi():
h = Label(root, text="Тест по английскому языку", font='Times 30', fg='#0F9')
inpansh = Button(root, text='Продолжить', font='Times 17', command=que_1)
h.grid(row=0)
inpansh.grid(row=2)

Comment: Кнопка по прежнему лезет во второе окно

Comment: Не сработало. Быть может проблема с def hi?